# object not rendered correctly when i take camera away from object in unity vuforia

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am rendering TV object on image target. it is working prefect in webcamera of pc. but then i compiled and installed in my android phone.

it is rendering fine when camera is too much near to target but i take it far, all texture become bright yellow type.

All material are in asset folder and most shaders used are "Standard"

Screenshot 1. when camera is near to target
Screenshot 2. when camera is far
visit link :
http://techbytes.byethost6.com/online/storage/ABC/screeshot.png

(was not able to upload image because pf reputation is low and it require 10+..just asking question first time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem..

Actually it was problem of Unsupported Shaders in Android...
I used another Shader like "Bumped Specular" from Legacy Shader.

And yes, you need to attach light source from proper direction to make it look nice and realistic..
otherwise it may look all dark.

Answer (score 0):

Do you by chance have a light attached to the ARCamera? From the screenshots, it looks like a very bright directional light is shining on the second screenshot.

Comment: actually it was problem of unsupported shaders in android...
just used another shader like "Legacy Shader/Bump Specular"..